# Show text on polygon android Google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, text, polygon

I am using polygons on map and I want to have a text on them. Is there any possible way to do this?
 I tried to put simple text on map point but didn't make it.

```
 private void addPolygon(Region reg) {
             PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
             ArrayList<LatLng> coordList=reg.getAllPoints();
             coordList.add(coordList.get(0));
             int regColor = reg.getColor();
             String regName = reg.getName();
             //want to put a name on region
             polylineOptions.addAll(coordList);
             polylineOptions
              .width(5)
              .color(Color.BLACK);
             if (regColor != 0)
                 polylineOptions
                  .color(regColor);
             map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            //text on shape?
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a `Marker` with a custom icon, and draw the text on that icon. You can use a method like this:

```
public Marker addText(final Context context, final GoogleMap map,
        final LatLng location, final String text, final int padding,
        final int fontSize) {
    Marker marker = null;

    if (context == null || map == null || location == null || text == null
            || fontSize <= 0) {
        return marker;
    }

    final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

    final Paint paintText = textView.getPaint();

    final Rect boundsText = new Rect();
    paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, textView.length(), boundsText);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    final Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    final Bitmap bmpText = Bitmap.createBitmap(boundsText.width() + 2
            * padding, boundsText.height() + 2 * padding, conf);

    final Canvas canvasText = new Canvas(bmpText);
    paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvasText.drawText(text, canvasText.getWidth() / 2,
            canvasText.getHeight() - padding - boundsText.bottom, paintText);

    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpText))
            .anchor(0.5f, 1);

    marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

    return marker;
}
```

You will need to set the location `LatLng` of the marker and you will have to calculate it from your `Region` (for example the first point of the geometry, the last point, a random point, the centroid, ...).

Also, take into account that drawing a lot of markers will have a negative effect in the performance.

Comment: @noni_methadoni if this solution worked for you then please accept this answer so other people can use this method too.

Comment: @antonio can you please guide me changing the background color of the text, I want the label in a colored background. How can I  do that?

Comment: @MihodiHasanLushan you can try  doing `canvasText.drawColor(Color.RED);`

Answer (score 0):

And C#/Xamarin version if anyone needs:

```
public Marker AddText(Context context, GoogleMap map, LatLng location, string text, int fontSize)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));
    if (location == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(location));
    if (map == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(map));
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    if (fontSize <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fontSize));

    var textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.Text = text;
    textView.TextSize = fontSize;
    var paintText = textView.Paint;
    var boundsText = new Rect();
    paintText.GetTextBounds(text, 0, textView.Length(), boundsText);
    paintText.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
    paintText.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;
    var bmpText = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(boundsText.Width(), boundsText.Height(), Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    var canvasText = new Canvas(bmpText);
    canvasText.DrawText(text, canvasText.Width / 2, canvasText.Height - boundsText.Bottom, paintText);
    return map.AddMarker((new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(location).SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(bmpText)).Anchor(0.5f, 1)));
}
```