# I want to show distance on Polyline googlemap Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show distance of each connected node on polyline. Currently i am not getting such method to show the text over polyline. Please help is it possible to do in android google maps api.

Answer (score 1):

This method (Java) adds a polyline to the map and adds the distance of each segment as text on the polyline - using the referenced method in another answer for displaying the text.

```
private void polylineLabels() {
    LatLng pt1 = new LatLng(39.935484,-83.023490);
    LatLng pt2 = new LatLng(39.098487,-84.446861);
    LatLng pt3 = new LatLng(39.743435,-86.104479);
    LatLng pt4 = new LatLng(38.202789,-85.739295);
    LatLng pt5 = new LatLng(38.614276,-90.138124);

    routePts.add(pt1);
    routePts.add(pt2);
    routePts.add(pt3);
    routePts.add(pt4);
    routePts.add(pt5);

    for (int i = 1; i < routePts.size(); i++) {
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(
                new PolylineOptions()
                .add(routePts.get(i-1), routePts.get(i)).
                        width(5).color(Color.RED));
        double d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(routePts.get(i-1),routePts.get(i));
        int dInt = (int)d;
        String msg = Integer.toString(dInt)+"m";
        LatLng midpt = SphericalUtil.interpolate(routePts.get(i-1),routePts.get(i), 0.5);
        Marker m = addText(this, mMap, midpt, msg, 2, 18);
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

You'll have to experiment with offset location to better position each label.

Here's the answer which defines the `addText` method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185289/2711811 .

Comment: Thanks Alot Andy !

Comment: It's now working as i expected ! Thanks buddy.